# Problem concerning inscribed and circumscribed circles...

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

Can you please help me solve this really difficult problem: Find R/r where R is the radius of the circumscribed circle of a trapezoid and r is the radius of the inscribed circle of this trapezoid.

Thank you very much for your trying to help, in advance ![image]

Comment: What are you given? I don' quite understand. If you know the radius's, then what do you have to find out?

Comment: The only information given is: --a trapezoid  --in this trapezoid we have an inscribed circle and also a circle circumscribed to it    --- next, we have that the radius of inscribed circle is 'r' but of circumscribed circle is "R". So now, we have to find R/r, and I know that it should be an exact value.  I hope I was clear if not please ask me , thank you that you looked at my problem.

Comment: I don't understand what you are given, the sides or angles of the trapezoid? if you have r and R then R/r follows immediately.

Comment: I have only the radiuses of the circumscribed and inscribed (R and r )circles , and, in other words, I have to find the ratio between R and r/

Comment: @Sawarnik We don't have the exact values of R and r their just, as variables

Comment: Thanks, that clears up. Since you don't have the values of radiuses, what do you have? Sides?

Comment: Nothing, only the radiuses, that's all. I know it may sound weird but now I am searching and I found that what I am looking for was once proven by Fejes Toth

Comment: @Sawarnik That's also my first thought about this question until I found that the solution of this question is an inequality. I've given John the links and a complete free journal about the proof in my answer below.

Comment: @Tunk-Fey Oh, I see. But he asked for the exact value, that was confusing.

Comment: @JohnG. Why didn't you upload the picture from the beginning. OK, let me clarify several things. Are you sure the picture of the problem like that? Is $\overrightarrow{BC}$ not tangent to the inner circle? Does $\overrightarrow{BC}$ have no contact with the inner circle?

Comment: @Tunk-Fey Excuse me, I uploaded the image, and I think it's finally so. Thank you Tunk-Fey for you persistence, I really appreciate it.

Comment: @JohnG. No worries, I'm really enjoy your question. Besides, I'm on fire right now. Hahaha... Anyway, I've added my answer. The answer is $$\frac{R}{r}=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{5}}.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your answer is given on these links: [Isosceles tangential trapezoid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangential_trapezoid#Isosceles_tangential_trapezoid) and [Bicentric quadrilateral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicentric_quadrilateral).

---

**UPDATE :**

This [journal](http://www.emis.de/journals/JIPAM/images/118_04_JIPAM/118_04.pdf) can answer your question, just click and it will automatically download the journal. I found this journal in the link that I gave to you. I hope this help.

---

Your question can be solved by using Fuss' theorem (you can see this theorem on the links that I gave to you). Fuss' theorem gives a relation between the inradius $r$, the circumradius $R$ and the distance $x$ between the center of the inner circle and center of the outer circle, for any bicentric quadrilateral (trapezoid is included). The relation is
$$
\frac{1}{(R-x)^2}+\frac{1}{(R+x)^2}=\frac{1}{r^2}.
$$
In this case, using your picture, we have $x=r$. Therefore
$$
\frac{1}{(R-r)^2}+\frac{1}{(R+r)^2}=\frac{1}{r^2}.\tag1
$$
By using equation $(1)$, I think it is not difficult to obtain that:
$$
\frac{R}{r}=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{5}}.
$$

$$\\$$

---

$$\Large\color{blue}{\text{# }\mathbb{Q.E.D.}\text{ #}}$$

Comment: No its not I need. In my problem I know only the radiuses and that's all

Comment: @JohnG. Are you sure? If so, then the answer is simply$$\frac{R}{r}\ge\sqrt{2}.$$Just please take a look this same [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicentric_quadrilateral#Inequalities_2) carefully. :)

Comment: It's the direct answer but I would like to see the explanation. Thank you for the link ,I will try more!

Comment: @JohnG. Please read carefully my friend. The answer is directly in front of your eyes. Let me give you a hint: **the equality holds only when the two circles are concentric (have the same center as each other); then the quadrilateral is a square**. Now, using the hint, I believe you can derive that inequality. :)

Comment: @JohnG. This [journal](http://www.emis.de/journals/JIPAM/images/118_04_JIPAM/118_04.pdf) can answer your question, just click and it will automatically download it. I found this journal in the link that I gave to you.

Comment: Fey This is the graph. Sorry for so much confusion.

Comment: @Sawarnik Thank you. I don't even realize that here in Indonesia is already 3 a.m. This problem is really bugging me as if it asked to be solved. **:D**